# grails beans definition returns null pointer exception

Tags: spring, grails, mongo-java

I'm trying to define a bean for class that will handle connections to mongodb
beans definition

```
beans = {
    dbCon(DbConnImpl){
        mongoClient = ref("mongo_client")
        dbName = "myDb"
    }

    mongo_client(MongoClient, "localhost", 27017)
    }
```

DbConnImpl:

```
class DbConnImpl {
    MongoClient mongoClient
    String dbName

    public DB getDB(){
        return mongoClient.getDB(dbName)
    }

    void setMongoClient(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient
    }

    void setDbName(String dbName) {
        this.dbName = dbName
    }
}
```

and the usage:

```
class UserController {
    DbConnImpl dbConn


    def index() {
        DB db = dbConn.getDB()

        def colls = db.getCollectionNames()
        render colls
    }
}
```

error: NullPointerException : Cannot invoke method getDB() on null object

Can someone please advise?
Thanks!
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your bean is `dbCon` so you need the same name in the controller:

```
class UserController {
    DbConnImpl dbCon
}
```

Comment: if i could five myself -1 for this question...i would /-:. didn't see the typo